# Build Fails only when publishing

Tags: c#, deployment, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, publish

I'm running visual studio 2017, I'm trying to FTP deploy a .net-core 2.0 project to my server.  My project builds fine normally but when I attempt to publish I get an error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__2()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

This issue only occurs when I publish.  A bunch of error popup in the output window for third party dlls `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`

Any idea on how I can get publish working?

Comment: that is a bit unusual, but I've found publish does attempt to use separate settings files for some types of projects.  Are you doing an async await/task when reading AppSettings? do you have DependencyInjection framework setup?

Comment: @BrettCaswell all of my controllers are async but I don’t manually read from app settings at all

Comment: also, have you tried a local release build to see if you can't reproduce this?  typically we build and test in debug and publish in release.  there may be a configuration issue you aren't experiencing because of the directives.

Comment: Updating my visual studio fixed this issue

Comment: For anyone else experiencing this issue.  The way I can consistently publish is, publish locally to a folder first, and then manully ftp that folder to the server

Comment: do you mean that when you build it doesn't get any errors? if yes this is what I said!!
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133405/cannot-publish-to-azure/51333100#51333100

Comment: @ma1169 I'm not using MVC, I have no cshtml files

Comment: the point is when you publish(not when you build), in your error list do you see anything?

Comment: @ma1169 no, there are no errors in the error list

Answer (score 3):

For what it's work, I had the exact same error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
```

And the remote server was out of disk space. The publish console didn't show anything after the publish, but if I scroll up I start to see this:

```
2>Unable to add 'Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js' to the Web site.  Unable to add file 'Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.js'.  There is not enough space on the disk.
```

Moral of the story this error *seems* to point towards something external to the project itself. Hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at FolderProfile.pubxml file located in YourProject\Properties\PublishProfiles and make sure  term is configured with correct version.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Select "Publish" in the Menu then create "+New" to create publish profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For VS2019 and IIS 10, Recycling the application pool the application uses that you're deploying worked for me.