# Cannot publish to azure

Tags: django, visual-studio, azure

I have developed a Django app using Visual Studio Community Edition.

I am unable to deploy it to Azure, getting a temp file containing following exception:

> 02-07-2018 15:07:22 System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window
>   for more details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__116.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Comment: try stopping your service restart and deploy

Comment: Update your Visual-studio to the latest version and try again

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could be due to network or stop the fiddler if it is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Check  compiler errors!! Do you have other errors?

When you play code in debug mode, most of the code errors detected at  runtime  so the code won’t be detected unless it’s run it, when you publish your code for some reason, it check all cshtml for errors before publishing so hidden errors could be detected hence it won’t be published.
I had the same problem and I had CSHTML files which I didn’t need and I didn’t  call it in my code, so after deleting these file my code run smoothly.
It’s not a problem with publishing, but you can say you have an unhandled error in your code, an error that appear as run time in debug mode but compiler error when you publish